# Locust: sequentially running several different tests

Tags: locust

We have several locust tests, with different load requirements (different number of users, different wait_time). They need to run sequentially overnight, which we currently do with separate invocations.
E.g.

```
# file ordering.py:
class OrderingUser(HttpUser):
   wait_time=between(20,30)
   @task 
   def order_normal(self):...
   @task 
   def order_discounted(self):...

# file catalogue.py:
class CatalogueUser(HttpUser):
   wait_time=between(2,3)
   @task
   def search(self):...
```

Then we invoke sequentially:

```
First invoke:
locust -f ordering.py --users 3 --run-time 2h

After it finishes, we invoke:
locust -f catalogue.py --users 10 --run-time 2h

And finally merge the reports into a single file
```

The question please: does locust have any built-in support for this (including merging the reports at the end)? Or do we need to keep invoking & coordinating this externally?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want [Custom Load Shapes](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html), which is a class that contains code deciding when to have what users do what. For your use case specifically, see the docs which have an example showing exactly what you want: [spawning different user types after a certain amount of time](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html?#restricting-which-user-types-to-spawn-in-each-tick).

```
class StagesShapeWithCustomUsers(LoadTestShape):

    stages = [
        {"duration": 10, "users": 10, "spawn_rate": 10, "user_classes": [UserA]},
        {"duration": 30, "users": 50, "spawn_rate": 10, "user_classes": [UserA, UserB]},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 100, "spawn_rate": 10, "user_classes": [UserB]},
        {"duration": 120, "users": 100, "spawn_rate": 10, "user_classes": [UserA,UserB]},
    ]

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        for stage in self.stages:
            if run_time < stage["duration"]:
                try:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"], stage["user_classes"])
                except:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"])
                return tick_data

        return None
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks so much